How to deposit Money in USD without losing in exchange rate
I have two bank accounts in Canada: one with Scotiabank and the other with Tangerine (an online bank).
My Scotiabank account is only in Canadian dollars, while my Tangerine account has both Canadian and USD options.
I have $5,000 USD in cash and want to deposit it into my Tangerine USD account. However, Tangerine has no physical branches, so they don’t accept cash deposits.
Opening a USD account at Scotiabank would involve fees. Is there a fast and easy way to deposit this cash into my Tangerine USD account?

Honestly I am at a loss.  I like to travel internationally and have no idea how to get a good price on my destination currency.  It seems like the kiosks at the airports are about the best deal.  They tend to be far better deals then banks themselves.  Most of the time, I use a card and get a good exchange rate that way.  ATMs are a rip off.

It looks like Tangerine allows deposits through Scotiabank ABMs, have you checked?

Are you sure opening a USD account at Scotiabank would involve fees? Often the fees are waived if you maintain some minimum balance. Did you check?

Indeed, the only way is to have an account in USD.

Even of you have a bank account in USD in Canada it’s not obvious to me deposits in USD cash are necessarily possible or free.

@littleadv https://www.tangerine.ca/en/faq/how-can-i-deposit-us-currency “Deposits to a US$ Savings Account can't be made at an ABM.”

@jcaron sounds like an answer

Tangerine say they accept USD money orders. One option would then be to cross the border (hoping you not too far from it) and buy 5 $1000 money orders and send them to Tangerine. It will cost you 5 x $3.40 in fees though.

I discovered that Scotia ATMs allow deposits into Tangerine accounts, though I'm not certain if that applies to USD deposits.
Additionally, I found out that I can open a no-fee USD account at Scotia Bank.

As detailed in comments above, they explicitly state you can’t deposit USD through ABMs. Only checks, drafts, money orders or transfers are possible. In short: no cash.
